# kubeflow pipeline dynamic output list as input parameter

Tags: python, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I use a ParallelFor over a dynamic list. I want to collect all the outputs from the loop, and pass them to another ContainerOp.
 Something like the following, which obviously does not work, since the `outputs` list is will be static.

```
with dsl.ParallelFor(op1.output) as item:
    op2 = dsl.ContainerOp(
      name='op2',
      ...
      file_outputs={
         'outputs': '/outputs.json',
    })
    outputs.append(op2.output)


op3 = dsl.ContainerOp(
   name='op3',
   ...
   arguments=['--input': outputs]  # won't work
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the solution of Ark-kun is not working for me. But there is a simple way to implement fan-in workflow if we know the number of inputs in advance. We may precalculate pipeline DAG like that:

```
@kfp.components.create_component_from_func
def my_transformer_op(item: str) -> str:
    return item + "_NEW"


@kfp.components.create_component_from_func
def my_aggregator_op(items: list) -> str:
    return "HELLO"


def pipeline(array_of_arguments):
    @dsl.pipeline(PIPELINE_NAME, PIPELINE_DESCRIPTION)
    def dynamic_pipeline():
        outputs = []
        for i in array_of_arguments:
            outputs.append(my_transformer_op(str(i)).output)
        my_aggregator_op(outputs)
    return dynamic_pipeline

...

    run_id = client.create_run_from_pipeline_func(
        pipeline(data_samples_chunks), {},
        run_name=PIPELINE_RUN,
        experiment_name=PIPELINE_EXPERIMENT).run_id
```

[image: Pipeline graph]

Answer (score 4):

I have run into issues with dynamic "fanning-out" and then "fanning-in" with Kubeflow Pipelines as well. Maybe a little heavy-handed but I used a mounted PVC claim to get over this.

Kubeflow allows you to mount a known PVC or create a new one on the fly using `VolumeOp` (link [here](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/pipelines/sdk/manipulate-resources/#volumeop)). This snippet shows how to use a known PVC.

```
    pvc_name = '<available-pvc-name>' 
    pvc_volume_name = '<pvc-uuid>' # pass the pvc uuid here

    # Op 1 creates a list to iterate over
    op_1 = dsl.ContainerOp(
            name='echo',
            image='library/bash:4.4.23',
            command=['sh', '-c'],
            arguments=['echo "[1,2,3]"> /tmp/output.txt'],
            file_outputs={'output': '/tmp/output.txt'})

    # Using withParam here to iterate over the results from op1
    # and writing the results of each step to its own PVC
    with dsl.ParallelFor(op_1.output) as item:
        op_2 = dsl.ContainerOp(
            name='iterate',
            image='library/bash:4.4.23',
            command=['sh', '-c'],
            arguments=[f"echo item-{item} > /tmp/output.txt; "  # <- write to output  
                       f"mkdir -p /mnt/{{workflow.uid}}; "  # <- make a dir under /mnt
                       f"echo item-{item}\n >> /mnt/{{workflow.uid}}"],  # <- append results from each step to the PVC
            file_outputs={'output': '/tmp/output.txt'},
            # mount the PVC
            pvolumes={"/mnt": dsl.PipelineVolume(pvc=pvc_name, name=pvc_volume_name)})

    op_3 = dsl.ContainerOp(
            name='echo',
            image='library/bash:4.4.23',
            command=['sh', '-c'],
            arguments=[f"echo /mnt/{{workflow.uid}} > /tmp/output.txt"],
            # mount the PVC again to use
            pvolumes={"/mnt": dsl.PipelineVolume(pvc=pvc_name, name=pvc_volume_name)},
            file_outputs={'output': '/tmp/output_2.txt'}).after(op_2)
```

Ensure that `op_3` runs after the loops from `op_2` using `after(op_2)` in the end.

Note: This might be a heavy-handed approach and there might be better solutions if KFP allows this as part of the KF compiler but I couldn't get it to work. If it's easy to create a PVC in the env this might work for your case.

Comment: I was thinking of writing to shared storage, this does work, but I hoped for a better kubeflow oriented solution, as this force the container to "know" that it is running in a loop

Comment: Unrelated note: Please use `component.yaml` files instead of manually creating `ContainerOp` instances. The componenents are as easy to create, but are reusable and portable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `op3` is not properly referencing the output from `op2` as an input argument. Try this:

```
op3 = dsl.ContainerOp(
    ...
    arguments=['--input': op2.outputs['outputs']]
)
```

Comment: Isn't this will reference only that last op2? Since there are multiple of them. Or there's some kubeflow magic here

Comment: Yes, I did see this in the documentation some time ago. I haven't check it recently. However, I wrote a blog on this: https://ekababisong.org/kubeflow-for-poets/

Comment: `invalid spec: templates.for-loop-for-loop-1a944bdb-1.outputs failed to resolve {{tasks.test-step-2.outputs.parameters.test-step-2-output}}`